# Unable To Find My App On The App Store ( iTunes )

Tags: iphone, mac-app-store, itunes-store

One more time i want your Help.

before 10 days i open iTunes and found my App on App Store and copied the link for some purpose
Below is link for my App :

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/naughty-cam-plus-naughtiest/id493891454?mt=8
Link was working fine (app store was showing my App).

But, Today i opened same link it is showing Me Error during Loadingtime of Apps as:

**Your request could not be completed.**

**"The item you've requested is not currently available in the Indian Store".**

Please give me some advice how to resolve this..

**Thanks a Lot for your help in Advance**

Comment: Not a programming related question. Try looking in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Considering the name of the app my guess is that Apple has removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to access it it says it's only available in the Indian App Store, but since it obviously isn't, my guess is that Apple has removed the app (just looking at the URL tells me that it probably is).

I suggest you check the app's status in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Hii Emil, Thanks for reply
In my App Store that application is not showing..(for which the link i gave). and showing the same Error which i mentioned in my Question.

Comment: What is this ?? Why am getting Negative Reputation for this Question ? Can any body tell me ????

Comment: As you can see, this question was closed for not being programming related. That, plus being pretty poorly written, are the most likely reasons for people to vote it down.